# ClassWizard to import TypeLibrary ADO

Tags: mfc, ado

I do the follwing :- import the type library using classWizard to import msado15.dll

whene finish the importing every thing seems to be ok , the classes of (ado,_recordset,....) were appears in the classView tree

my Questions is that :-

1. is this the right way to use **Ado** in **mfc** ?
2. is that way canceling needing of **#import** dirctive ?
3. how can i complete the connections and get records using that way ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the class wizard is different than using #import. Both create wrapper around the COM interfaces. 
YOu either use the MFC wrappers by the class wizard or the COM-Wrapper created by #import.

I usually always use #import with raw_interfaces_only and never relay on the wrappers created by #import or MFC. 
I have the best experience in using the raw COM interfaces and directly checking the HRESULTs and using ATL Smartpointers.

Answer (score 0):

The class wizard lets you import interfaces from a type library and builds MFC wrapping classes for those interfaces. The `#import` directive also imports interfaces from a type library but builds 'smart' COM-wrappers around them.

The two are not mutually exclusive, but I don't see the point of using both.

Here are some additional readings for you:

- [Adding an MFC Class from a Type Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06teee.aspx)
- [#import Directive (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx)

Comment: well guys , the both answers are nice                                  , the question some times hurts which is :- why not mfc just use adodb as easy as Visual Basic  .